# Chrome Plugin - jQuery access child nodes of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to create a Chrome Plugin which ads a link to each li-element of a defined ul.
I have problems to access this element with jQuery.

I tried `const ideaList = $("ul.idea-list");` but cannot get access to it.

I only access an element which is very high in the DOM. const mainContent = $("#main-content");
So i tried to get down with to the children() and find("*"), but it does not work.
It has alwaysthe length of 0.

[image]

```
<div data-v-32ba3100="" id="main-content" class="clearfix"><!----> 
  <div data-v-4396a345="" data-v-32ba3100="" class="designlist page-wrapper">
    <multiple divs>
    <div data-v-0f00a344="" data-v-4396a345="" class="design-list-view">
          <ul data-v-0f00a344="" class="idea-list">
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
```

This is the selector copied from DevTools
#main-content > div > div > div > div > div.design-list-view > ul > li

// content.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const mainContent = $("#main-content"); // works

    const children = mainContent.find("*"); //not working

    const ideaList = $("ul.idea-list"); // not working
    console.log(ideaList);
    if (ideaList.length > 0) {
        // Select all <li> elements within the 'idea-list' <ul> using jQuery
        const liElements = ideaList.find("li");

        // Loop through the <li> elements and add a link to each one using jQuery
        liElements.each(function () {
            const link = $("<a>", {
                href: "https://www.example.com", // Replace with the desired link URL
                text: "Visit Example Website", // Replace with the desired link text
            });

            $(this).append(link);
        });
    }
```

});

Comment: `const ideaList = $("ul.idea-list");` would work if it is present at the time your script runs. Try it in the console after the UL is present. If that does not work, then there is a chance that it is not in the same DOM. For example if they use an iFrame

Comment: This shows up if i enter: console.log($("ul.idea-list"));

<ul data-v-0f00a344 class=​"idea-list">​<li data-v-0f00a344 class=​"idea-list-heading">​…​</li>​flex<li data-v-0f00a344>​…​</li>​<li data-v-0f00a344>​…​</li>​<li data-v-0f00a344>​…​</li>​<li data-v-0f00a344>​…​</li>​<li data-v-0f00a344>​…​</li>​

Comment: So you need to defer your script until the UL exists in the page - it seems it is loaded after the page has loaded. Can you check that?

Comment: Then you can shorten it to `$("ul.idea-list li").each(function() { ... };`

Comment: mplungjan, i do not know ho to do that. I added "run_at": "document_end" to the content_scripts, but this has no effect.

Comment: This is a modern site which adds elements dynamically. Use MutationObserver to wait for the element.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm. Added a Oberserver and now it works. Learned a lot today. Thank you.
Added the Observer from this Gist: https://gist.github.com/jwilson8767/db379026efcbd932f64382db4b02853e

Answer (score 0):

Added a MutationOberserver to the element ul.idea-list li. So the process starts only if the elements exists.